Is there any notion of spin-statistics in curved spacetime?
It is a well established fact that all known particles obey either Fermi-Dirac statistics (for fermions) or Bose-Einstein statistics (for bosons), at least in the context of relativistic quantum mechanics on Minkowski spacetime. In fact, the concept of ''particle" relies on the representation theory of the Poincaré group, which is the symmetry group of Minkowski. Moreover, in QFT, one usually interpret the creation of a particle as the action of a field $\hat{\varphi}(x)$ as operators on a particular state, i.e., the vacuum $|0\rangle$. Then, the spin-statistics is a statement on the commutation relations obeyed by these fields.
However, in a curved spacetime we don't have the same structure. In general there is no global Poincaré symmetry (although locally still remains), but also the vacuum is not uniquely defined.
I wonder then if there is any natural and well defined notion of spin-statistics in the context of quantum field theory in curved spacetime. If yes, are there any reliable resources from where to study it? And if not, how do we even make sense of particles moving on a curved background?

It is a very known result by R. Verch https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002200100526

Thanks for the reference!

We can introduce objects transforming under general representations of the Lorentz group on curved spacetimes. Of course, this is only possible locally. The way to extend this to the full manifold is then done by specifying how these objects can be transported along the manifold. Formally this amounts to introducing a spinor bundle to our manifold (for spinor reps) and equivalently different e.g. vector bundles for vectors etc.
For quantization, we can then e.g. canonically quantize the resulting (curved spacetime) equation of motion just as you would in the case of e.g. free scalars in curved spacetimes. (For a review of how one quantizes scalars in curved spacetime see e.g. Harvey Reall Part 3 Black Holes)

Thanks for the reply! In the reference provided there is a mention to one of the concerns I have (pag. 126), i.e., there is no preferred notion of the subspace of positive frequency solutions that one requires to properly define the inner product and then the Hilbert space (except under particular conditions). If the canonical (anti-)commutation relations (CCRs) are defined in terms of the inner product -which is not uniquely defined in general curved spacetimes- then the notion of "fermion" or "boson" based on the CCRs seems to be meaningless in general curved spacetimes. Is that correct?

I think the idea is more generally that the notion of a (single) particle is not well defined (which follows directly from the non-existence of a unique vacuum in the absence of a global timelike killing vector field).  However (at least for non-interacting theories) the expansion of a state in positive modes with respect to a different vacuum should not mix commuting and anticommuting operators I think.
